# under which directory can i find the packages installed using yum

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

where do the packages installed using the `yum` command go ? For example i installed some dependencies using the command :

```
yum -y install kernel-devel kernel-headers
```

Where can i find these installed ? *(I mean under which directory)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `yum-utils` installed, use

```
 repoquery -ql kernel-devel
```

or

```
 repoquery --list kernel-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

Every package is different.  kernel source will go under /lib,  some programs under /opt or /usr/local.  It depends on your distros defaults and the packager (althought there are standards)